# How to fix Jquery sliding panel issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to flip a div panel left once a some item div get clicked and hide,once item div get clicked again. (exactly like new twitter reading panel).

i have tried several methods but i couldn't animate it smooth.
recently i identified it not happen smoothly because of the bad what have i done.i increased width of outter div and decrese width.

are there any good suggestion or code snippet to work my need??

Here is the code that i have used for animate and gt show the more read div panel

```
$("#more-item").animate({"width": "toggle"}, { duration: 500,specialEasing: {width: 'linear', height: 'easeOutBounce'} });
```

Here is the scenario that i need to see.

```
1. clicked on item div
2. more read div panel animate and flip to left and show the
3. click again item div
4. more read div panel animate and flip right and hide
```

when we at third point if we again click another item div just load content of recent clicked div instead animate and hide the more read div

here is the screen shot what my need functioning on new twitter reading panel.
[image]

Comment: Could you put this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with example html?

Comment: Second the request for a fiddle. And a question out of own experience: the 450px are accurate? If you'd push it to far to the left, you would naturally always experience a delay.

Comment: @ polarblau i'm not a css and html expert only what can i see with my code is there is a error with my code could you please explain how to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this by adding a fixed positioned `<div>` to the right, wrap your items in a container and animate the panel and the container's margin accordingly.

The trick is to use the `top`, `bottom` and `right` css properties to position the reading panel.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wUGaY/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">One</div>
    <div class="item">Two</div>
    <div class="item">Three</div>
    <div class="item">Four: This contains a bit longer text to test if wrapping is working correctly.</div>
    <div class="item">Five</div>
    <div class="item">Six</div>
    <div class="item">Seven</div>
    <div class="item">Eight</div>
    <div class="item">Nine</div>
    <div class="item">Ten</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:200px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    background-color:white;
}

.item {
    border:1px solid #eee;
    padding:20px;
}

.active {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    function showPanel() {
        // Show the panel and animate it into view
        $('.panel').stop().show().animate({
            right: '0px'
        });
        // Animate the container's margin to make room
        // for the reading panel
        $('.container').stop().animate({
            marginRight: '232px'
        });
    }

    function hidePanel() {
        // Move the panel off the screen and hide it when done
        $('.panel').stop().animate({
            right: '-232px'
        }, function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });

        // Animate the container's margin back to normal
        $('.container').stop().animate({
            marginRight: '0px'
        });
    }

    // Hide the panel initially and set its position
    $('.panel').hide().css('right','-232px');

    // What happens when they click on inactive items?
    $('.container').delegate('.item:not(.active)', 'click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        // Make the current item the only active item
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');

        // Add some content to the reading panel
        $('.panel').html($this.html());

        // Show the reading panel
        showPanel();
    });

    // What happens when they click on an active item?
    $('.container').delegate('.active', 'click', function() {
        // Make it inactive
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        // Hide the reading panel
        hidePanel();
    });
});
```

Comment: wow well done could you please check this for me i ave no idea.http://jsfiddle.net/gayancc/tjbEs/